# Sort list of dictionaries with inconsistent keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort a list of dictionaries.
The problem is that key in the dictionaries are not same, but every dictionary will have only one item for sure.
For example, `[{'foo':39}, {'bar':7}, {'spam':35}, {'buzz':4}]`
Here, key is the name of the person and value is the age.
I want result as `[{'buzz': 4}, {'bar': 7}, {'spam': 35}, {'foo': 39}]`
What I am doing is :

```
def get_val(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        return v

sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda d: get_val(d))
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: I believe this question has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: lambda d: next(d.values())?

Comment: @rv.kvetch.  Actually `next(iter(d.values())`.  (Your solution was the first thing I tried and I got an error.)

Comment: @wikikikitiki I have gone through the link. That was a different problem.

Comment: @FrankYellin thanks, I was looking for something like that only to avoid a function just to return the value

Comment: @soumya-kole, yes you are right, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use values of `dict` in `lambda` like below :

```
>>> lst_dct = [{'foo':39}, {'bar':7}, {'spam':35}, {'buzz':4}]

>>> sorted(lst_dct, key=lambda x: list(x.values()))
[{'buzz': 4}, {'bar': 7}, {'spam': 35}, {'foo': 39}]
```

You can extent this for use list with multi elements:

```
>>> lst_dct = [{'foo':[39, 40]}, {'bar':[7,8]}, {'spam':[4,5]}, {'buzz':[4,6]}]

>>> sorted(lst_dct, key=lambda x: sorted(x.values()))
[{'spam': [4, 5]}, {'buzz': [4, 6]}, {'bar': [7, 8]}, {'foo': [39, 40]}]
```